# Not fill content into div

Tags: css, html

I have to print some content on a div but I need it not ajust itself into the div width

For example if my text is "Some text to explain this situation" and my div width can only contain about 10 characters I want it to show

```
Some tex
```

instead of this[(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/Xfrnw/2/):

```
Some
text to
explain 
this 
situation
```

Is it possible? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I remove it I'll get [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/Xfrnw/7/) besides I need to add width:35% for the design of the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
.container{
    width:9%;
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfrnw/8/

---

If you only want to show the first line, add the following:

```
line-height: 1em;
height: 1em;
overflow: hidden;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfrnw/9/

---

**Why both `word-wrap` and `overflow-wrap`?**

Quoting from [this Mozilla page](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap):

> Originally a Microsoft (unprefixed) proprietary extension, the
>   word-wrap property has been renamed overflow-wrap in the current draft
>   of the CSS3 Text specification. Stable builds of Google Chrome and
>   Opera support the new syntax.

Comment: For the single line case, `width: 9%; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;` would also work, but it would cut of words in the middle of letters instead of showing as many full characters as can fit.

Comment: @mooseman is it possible to do it without use `height: 1em;` ? I want to use `height:10%` or something like that.

Comment: @Andres `height: 1em` ensures that only one line of text will appear. A dynamic value such as `10%` may cause partial lines of text to appear. (I used `height: 1.5em` to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/Xfrnw/10/)

Comment: @mooseman You are right, but it can be done as JoelSpadin said [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aras7/Xfrnw/11/)

Comment: @Andres That method will also only show a single line of text. However, unlike my second fiddle, and as JoelSpadin pointed out, it may cut words in the middle of a character, instead of forcing it to the next (hidden) line.